# Find surface integral. I think I need help setting up the problem

Tags: surface-integrals

> Evaluate the integral for the given data. Describe the kind of surface. Show the details of your work.

$$F = [0,x,0]$$
$$S: x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 1, x \geq 0, y \geq 0 , z \geq 0$$

I'm trying to find a parameterized version of S.

$x = cos \theta sin \theta, y = sin \theta sin \theta$ and z = $cos \theta$
so I get $$r(u,v) = [cos \theta sin \theta, sin \theta sin \theta, cos \theta]$$
Is that right? Obv not since the terms are wrong, but what should the term be?

When I use the r as an input of F I get:

$$F = [0, cos \theta sin \theta, 0]$$

But then I can't differentiate r with respect to u because I wrote everyhting in $\theta$

Comment: It is not the same THETA everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

The parametrisation of  $ S $ should be

$$x=\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)$$
$$y=\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$$
$$z=\cos(\phi)$$
with
$$0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$$
and
$$0\le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: and does u correspond to theta and v to theo other symbol? Mind just going a bit more?

Comment: @Jwan622 Yes{}{}{}{}{}{}{}

Comment: Why elsewhere I see a different parametric representation of a sphere?

Comment: @Jwan622 What did you see elsewhere ?

Comment: @Jwan622 Here, it is just a part (1/8) of a sphere since $x\ge0 y\ge0 z\ge0$